Ignore lines of Javascript when running CodeQL
Qt have a distinct way of importing JavaScript resources from other JavaScript resources, where the syntax is:
.import "filename.js" as Qualifier
More about this syntax is found here.
The challenge with this is that it prevents CodeQL from reading our JavaScript files, as this is noted as a syntax error, with the following message:
Syntax errors prevent code from executing correctly. If a piece of code contains syntax errors, this most likely indicates that it is never run and thus is dead code that should be removed.
I have looked for any way to insert compiler directives or anything similar so that the static analysis would ignore these lines without luck.
Is there anyway to perform CodeQL analysis on JavaScript files used in Qt/QML applications where these import and pragma statements are present?

The JS in that file would still be parsed and included in the CodeQL database.  Unfortunately - any logic that would depend on understand that dependency tree would be incomplete and therefore lead to a less precise database. In general, if there is a way to transpile down to javascript/typescript, then you might see greater success by pointing CodeQL (via paths in codeql config ) at those converted files only.
